# Proper way to give id to any element

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am making a project to select date and time for making appointment( img below). I am giving id to label as combination of date and time. for example id
"2015-08-24 10:00 am" is given to label showing time 10:00 am.

[image: Select timeslot]

this is mandatory for me to give id like this to highlight all label falling under this service time slot.(in this case service time slot is of 170 min)
[image: timeslot selected]

till now it is working fine. but can it cause some problem in future for me to give id like this???

sorry for my poor english....................

Comment: an ID should not contain spaces, if you stick to html5 that's it. html4 has more specs: https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/html5-id-class

Comment: I would probably use a data attribute and make the value without spaces. For example: `data-timeid="201508241000am"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> can it cause some problem in future for me to give id like this?

*Maybe*, it depends on how you use them. But it's **invalid**, `id` values [cannot contain spaces](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-id-attribute).

Instead of using `id`, I'd suggest using a [`data-*` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-*-attributes), such as `data-value="2015-08-24 10:00 am"`.

If I were going to use that value in JavaScript, I'd also probably put that value in [the standard JavaScript form](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-date-time-string-format) (as of the most recent spec, this is a subset of ISO-8601; prior to that, the spec had an error in it which make it not quite a subset): `2015-08-24T10:00` (plus any timezone if relevant).